# iOS UIButton is always transparent

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, transparency

I have a custom view in an iphone app, which, when the conditions are met, should dim the screen and present some input fields to the user.

I have no issue disabling the main controls and "dimming" the screen (just a UIView with alpha=0.6), however the controls I am displaying on top of this always seem to have some transparency (I can read some of the text through a UIButton), even when I set the alpha of the control to 1.0 and set opaque=YES. I even tried putting an extra, opaque layer between the button and the overlay and it still is partially transparent.

For reference: (iOS 6.1)

```
UIView * overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:parentView.frame];
overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
overlay.alpha=0.6;

UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonRoundedRect];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
button.alpha = 1.0;
button.opaque = YES;
[button setTitle:@"done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,44.0,44.0)];

[overlay addSubview:button];
[parentView addSubview:overlay];
```

even with the above code the button is transparent. Does anyone know why and how to make the button opaque?

Comment: you mean to say you are getting alpha of button too is 0.6 .Am i right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can partially see through the `UIButton` is because it is a subview of the overlay `UIView` whose alpha is `0.6`. You'll need to do something like this:

```
// Create the overlay view just like you have it...
UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:parentView.frame];
overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
overlay.alpha = 0.6;

// Continue adding this to the parent view
[parentView addSubview:overlay];

// Create the button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonRoundedRect];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 44.0)];

// Add this button directly to the parent view
[parentView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Thank you, I was being very dumb it was obvious as soon as I read it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend of using the opaque feature, you will gain performance which is best practice:

- Making the button opaque by using the *IB*: choose the desired button and at the *Utilities* right side bar go to *Attributes Inspector* and in the *View* section mark *Opaque* and don't forget to change the background.
- Afterwards you will have to programmatically change the opaque for the label inside the UIButton:

  ```
  yourButtonOutlet.titleLabel.opaque = true;
  yourButtonOutlet.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor *YOUR DESIRED COLOR*];
  ```

Understand that using the opaque is recommended by [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringGraphicsPerformanceinYouriOSDevice/MeasuringGraphicsPerformanceinYouriOSDevice.html) for a fast rendering.